# Array formula to solve distance matrix

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

Help me with the following problem without adding any helper cells and changing the data:

"There are 8 cities in the country of Eight, A, B, C, D, E, F, G and H. Mr. Z decides to visit each city in his car starting from A. His planned itinerary is A-->B-->C-->D-->E-->F-->G-->H.

The distance between the cities is given in Table I."

Table I

```
Distance                                        
    A   B   C   D   E   F    G    H     
A   0   200                             
B   200 0   350                         
C       350 0   500                     
D           500 0   250                 
E               250 0   850             
F                   850 0    1250           
G                       1250 0    150       
H                            150  0
```

"Write a formula which takes the number of kms that Mr. Z has traveled from A as the input and displays the name of the city which is nearest to that point.

Mr. Z will enter the number of kms he has travelled from A in cell D30 and the name of the city nearest to the point will be displayed in E30"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: This is very clearly someone's homework assignment or something similar. As VTodorov mentioned, Stack Overflow is NOT a "please do my work for me" site. You have to make some semblance of an effort.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably a variation on the following (doesn't say can't hardcode cumulative sums)

```
=INDEX({"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"},MATCH(MIN(ABS({0,200,550,1050,1300,2150,3400,3350}-D30)),ABS({0,200,550,1050,1300,2150,3400,3350}-D30),0))
```